# Log scale in the parallel coordinates

Tags: r, plotly, parallel-coordinates

Is there a way to indicate that some of the parallel coordinates in R Plotly should be on the logarithmic scale? I have tried the following but it does not seem to work...

```
plot_ly(type = 'parcoords', 
               line = list(color = 'blue'),
               dimensions = list(
               list(range = c(1,5000),label = 'A', values = c(1,10,100,1000),axis = list(type = 'log')),
               list(range = c(1,5000),label = 'B', values = c(1,10,100,1000),axis = list(type = 'log'))
               )
             )
```

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48421782/plotly-parallel-coordinates-plot-axis-styling . it seems log scales were not supported in parcoords in January 2018.

Comment: I've missed that question. The strange thing is that the documentation https://plot.ly/r/reference/#parcoords has "dimensions -> axis -> type" with the explanation "Sets the axis type for this dimension's generated x and y axes. Note that the axis `type` values set in layout take precedence over this attribute." It seems to suggest that log-scale axes should be supported now...